# Initialize a vector of pairs in one line

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, std-pair

I want to initialize a std::vector (of std::pair), with `k` objects, with the pair of values shown below.

Here is my attempt:

```
// int k
std::vector <std::pair<Point::FT, int> >
    v(k, (std::numeric_limits<FT>::max(), -1));
```

The error:

```
usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h: In member function ‘void std::vector<T, Allocator>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_Integer, _Integer, std::__true_type) [with _Integer = int, _Tp = std::pair<float, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<float, int> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:340:4:   instantiated from ‘std::vector<T, Allocator>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = int, _Tp = std::pair<float, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<float, int> >, std::vector<T, Allocator>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<float, int> >]’
../Random_kd_tree.h:139:50:   instantiated from ‘void Random_kd_tree<DivisionSpace, Tree>::search_nn(std::vector<float>&, int, std::vector<std::pair<float, int> >&) [with DivisionSpace = Division_Euclidean_space, Tree = RKD<Division_Euclidean_space>]’
../main.cpp:51:30:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1080:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<float, int> >::_M_fill_initialize(std::vector<std::pair<float, int> >::size_type, int&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1080:4: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1122:7: note: void std::vector<T, Allocator>::_M_fill_initialize(std::vector<T, Allocator>::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::pair<float, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<float, int> >, std::vector<T, Allocator>::size_type = unsigned int, std::vector<T, Allocator>::value_type = std::pair<float, int>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1122:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::pair<float, int>&}’
```

Comment: You use `Point::FT` in one place and a bare `FT` in another -- did you mean to use `Point::FT` in the `std::numeric_limits` template?

Comment: Good point @cdhowie. Probably have using Point::FT in the file, but missed it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just switch to `{` `}` around the constructor arguments...

```
std::vector<std::pair<Point::FT, int>> v{k, {std::numeric_limits<FT>::max(), -1}};
```

See it running [here](http://ideone.com/mxCZ2k)

Comment: Oh yeah! That's what I was trying to do, but used parentheses instead!

Comment: @G.Samaras: it's a good idea to use `{ }` all the time from C++11 onwards - sometimes extra things will work / ambiguities will be avoided, and it handles all the old cases too....

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it's more modern.

Comment: Although it cost me some reputation, would like to believe that future users are going to be glad with it! :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Point::FT` is something for which `numeric_limits::max()` is valid,

```
std::vector <std::pair<Point::FT, int>>
        v(k, std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<FT>::max(), -1));
```