# Can't initialize std::tuple as std::pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, tuples

From my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776531/initialize-a-vector-of-pairs-in-one-line) about std::pair, I thought I would be able to do something like the following, but it won't compile.

```
typedef Point::FT float; 
std::vector<std::tuple<Point::FT, int, int> > branch{ (int)(max_leaf_check * mul_factor),
  { std::numeric_limits<Point::FT>::max(), -1 , -1} };
```

Error:

```
error: converting to ‘const value_type {aka const std::tuple<float, int, int>}’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {float, int, int}, <template-parameter-2-2> = void, _Elements = {float, int, int}]’
```

How do I fix it? If it can't be fixed, is there any other way to do the initialization in one line?

As a follow up, I can't even make it work with `push_back()`.

```
Point::FT new_dist;
size_t other_child_i, tree_i;
branch.push_back({new_dist, other_child_i, tree_i});
```

Similar error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I fix it?

You can't; the explicit constructor prevents implicit brace-initialisation.

> If it can't be fixed, is there any other way to do the initialization in one line?

```
std::make_tuple(std::numeric_limits<Point::FT>::max(), -1 , -1)
```

> As a follow up, I can't even make it work with `push_back()`.

```
branch.emplace_back(new_dist, other_child_i, tree_i);
```

Comment: `branch` is a vector that is actually a `std::heap`. I  assume that replacing `push_back()` with `emplace_back` won't produce any problem. Right? Also, if you could kindly say a bit more about why my attempt can't be fixed? Your answer works, I just want to understand and learn, if possible.